# Migration of questions from [fstab] and [kernel] on AO.SE to U.SE

Tags: discussion, migration

SE.AO has a lot of questions with these two tags. They're not appropriate there imho because they have *nothing* to do with Ubuntu specifically. Would anyone object to questions being moved here -- unless they have some relic of Ubuntu-specificness that is added?

Find [the discussion on AO.SE over here](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/5330/29097).

Comment: "because they have nothing to do with Ubuntu specifically" - that's not the right way of seeing things. They're _relevant_ to Ubuntu. They're valuable for Ubuntu users.

Comment: @Mat What? *Food* is relevant to UNIX&Linux users because it keeps us running the same way the Linux kernel keeps Ubuntu running. And yet we'd probably migrate questions about ravioli to [Seasoned Advice](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/). *Relevancy* doesn't matter. *Specificity* matters.

Answer (score 6):

Questions that are of good quality but not about Ubuntu as defined in the Ask Ubuntu FAQ are generally welcome here, and we do get a trickle of migrated questions about Mint and other Ubuntu derivatives.

Questions that are on-topic on Ask Ubuntu are not and should not be migrated away from Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: That's exactly what I was asked. I only asked for approval here because a moderator of AU wanted a mod here to consent to it.

Comment: @EvanCarroll why doesn't said moderator just hit us up on mod chat? I realize we're slow to response but AFAIK we respond.

Comment: maybe he would I just took it like he was asking me if I got permission for and I figure I'd better do that... So I did.

Comment: @xenoterracide Meta is exactly the right place for a discussion like this. Chat is handy for a one-off query, but policy is made on meta.